# Como saber si tengo una array dentro de un objeto

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

en mi caso lo que quiero hacer es saber si tengo una array dentro de un objeto, la cosa es que no siempre seria igual, el codigo seria algo asi:

```
var persona = {
     "juan": {
         casa: {
             calle: "calle",
             numero: "1",
             piso: {
                 planta: "1",
                 puerta: "1"
             },
         },
         telefono:"612345789",
     },
     "ana": {
        casa: {
            calle: "calle2",
            numero: "2",
            piso: {
                planta: "2",
                puerta: "2"
            },
        },
        telefono:"612345789",
    }

 }
```

lo que me gustaria hacer es comprobar si existe "pedro", si es que si, comprobar la calle y en caso contrario que me lo cree

**MIS INTENTOS INSERVIBLES E INUTILES QUE NO VA HA SERVIR DE NADA PERO IGUAL LOS MUESTRO :**

```
    if (persona[this] != pedro) {
        persona.push("pedro{}");
    }

//otra prueba QUE NO HIZO EFECTO


persona[this] = casa[piso.planta="1"]
//otra mas
var pedro = "pedro";

persona = persona[pedro[piso.planta="1"]]

// hay mas pero como ya he dicho inservibles
```

**MI RESPUESTA FINAL**
En mi caso lo que hacemos es comprobar si la sesion actual esta guardada y en caso de que este inserta los valores de esta en los inputs de la paguina con la que trabajamos, si no existe la sesion generamos una nueva con los imputs mapeados y guardamos de nuevo

```
var sgid = $('#txt_sgid').val();

var hora = "12:30";

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
var selects = document.querySelectorAll("select");
var sesionesss = Object.keys(JSON.parse(localStorage.session));

if (sesionesss.includes(sgid)) {
    var sesion = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("session"))
    var objinputs = sesion[sgid].objinputs;
    var sesinput = objinputs["inputs"];
} else {
    var objinputs = {
        hora: "",
        selects: {},
        inputs: {},
    };

    var sesion = {};
    sesion[sgid] = {
        hora: hora,
        objinputs,


    }


}

mapearinputs();


function mapearinputs() {
    for (var i of inputs) {
        if (i.id == "conf_envio" || i.id == "conf_nno" || i.id == "conf_no" || i.id == "conf_ssi" || i.id == "texto1" || i.id == "texto2" || i.id == "texto3" || i.id == "texto4" || i.id == "texto5") {
            continue
        }


        i.value = sesinput[i.id];

        i.onchange = function() {
            objinputs.inputs[this.id] = this.value;
            localStorage.setItem("session", JSON.stringify(sesion));

        }
    }
    for (var s of selects) {


        s.onchange = function() {

            objinputs.selects[this.id] = this.value;
            localStorage.setItem("session", JSON.stringify(sesion));

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Lo intentaste resolver y no pudiste? Por favor agrega tu código para poder ayudarte.

Comment: @Marcos  he intentado solucionarlo y no me funciona, el codigo que tengo es inservible ya que no me deja buscar

Comment: Eso no importa, necesitamos que demuestres que minimamente lo has intentado. Al ver tu código podemos ayudarte a ver donde estan los errores y/o proponer mejores soluciones.

Comment: @Marcos ya te puse algunos que no me han servido, espero que te sirva : )

Comment: No te lo tomes mal, pero es evidente que te faltan conocimientos básicos de Javascript. Te recomiendo repasar todo de nuevo. [Trabajando con objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) y [Arreglos o Matrices](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays)

Comment: @Marcos ya me los he mirado anteriormente buscando como hacerlo, pero no me soluciono nada, no sale como hace que un string que coges de una variable sea el nombre de la nueva array o objeto, ni me dice como puedo insertar una array con objetos en su interior dentro de otra array o objeto : ) .
Aunque no lo creas ya llevo 3 dias destras de esto y aun no he encontradop la solucion, si falta conocimientos, pero para algo estoy estudiando : ) espero que tengas un agradable dia y gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: La comunidad espera que des señales de ser parte del esfuerzo por resolver tu propia duda. De ese modo sabemos que no estamos haciendole la tarea a alguien y mas gente querra responderte. Ese es uno de los motivos por los que alguien podria pedir tus intentos. Asi que mostrar tus intentos si sirve de algo.

Comment: @DanteS. Estoy haciendo pruebas ya que alguna respuesta me ha dado pequeños resultados, cuando tenga mi resultado optimo colgare la respuesta tranquilo, sinto ser un poco lento

Comment: @DanteS.  Ya esta respondido, comprueba si le parece bien

Comment: @Marcos Ya esta respondido, comprueba si le parece bien

Comment: Tranquilo, no te apuraba, solo te explicaba por que es útil mostrar tus intentos (cosa que ya hiciste)

Comment: Sobre tu respuesta final, te recomiendo responder tu propia pregunta (si, puedes hacerlo) con dicha respuesta y borrarla de la pregunta. De ese modo, quienes vean tu respuesta en el futuro la podrán identificar mejor ya que estará en la zona de respuestas. Además, si tu respuesta es buena, podrían votarte positivo c: Recuerda que luego de un tiempo podrás aceptar tu propia respuesta!

Comment: Y en cuanto a revisarla, no se nada de este lenguaje de programación. Vi tu pregunta en las colas de revisión, asi que no puedo decirte que opino de ella.

Comment: @DavidGonzalo, es bueno ver que has intentado resulver tu problema. Por otro lado, no veo que el código de la pregunta este reflejado en la respuesta (_que no debería estar dentro de tu pregunta_). La próxima vez usa tu caso real, tu código real. Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparto lo que te dicen en los comentarios de tu pregunta estás enfrascado en hacer cosas inservibles porque aún no tienes bien claros tus conocimientos hablas de array y en tu código no hay nigun array, los array van en estos corchetes cuadrados `[]`.

Puedes experimentar con el siguiente codigo

```js
var persona = {
  juan: {
    casa: {
      calle: "calle",
      numero: "1",
      piso: {
        planta: "1",
        puerta: "1",
      },
    },
    telefono: "612345789",
  },
  ana: {
    casa: {
      calle: "calle2",
      numero: "2",
      piso: {
        planta: "2",
        puerta: "2",
      },
    },
    telefono: "612345789",
  },
};

var nombresDePersona = Object.keys(persona);
console.log({ nombresDePersona });

if (!nombresDePersona.includes("pedro")) {
  console.info({
    mensaje: "No existe pedro",
  });
  persona["pedro"] = {
    casa: {
      calle: "calle3",
      numero: "3",
      piso: {
        planta: "3",
        puerta: "3",
      },
    },
    telefono: "613345789",
  };
}

console.log({
  persona,
});
```

pero lo recomendable si es trabajar con array

aquí te dejo un código diferente al tuyo que tendría un poco mas de sentido

```js
var personas = [
  {
    nombre: "juan",
    casa: {
      calle: "calle",
      numero: "1",
      piso: {
        planta: "1",
        puerta: "1",
      },
    },
    telefono: "612345789",
  },
  {
    nombre: "ana",
    casa: {
      calle: "calle2",
      numero: "2",
      piso: {
        planta: "2",
        puerta: "2",
      },
    },
    telefono: "612345789",
  },
];

let existePedro = personas.find((p) => p.nombre === "pedro");

console.log({ existePedro });

if (!existePedro) {
  personas.push({
    nombre: "pedro",
    casa: {
      calle: "calle3",
      numero: "3",
      piso: {
        planta: "3",
        puerta: "3",
      },
    },
    telefono: "613345789",
  });
}

console.log({ personas })
```

Answer (score 2):

Comprueba simplemente si existe la propiedad en tu objeto y si no la generas con la misma estructura que el resto:

```javascript
function check(name){
  if (name in persona){
    return persona[name]['casa']['calle'];
  } else {
    persona[name] = {
      casa: {
        calle: "",
        numero: "",
        piso: {
          planta: "",
          puerta: ""
        },
      },
      telefono:"",
    }
    return "Creada la persona " + name;
  }
}

console.log(check("ana"));
// calle2
console.log(check("pedro"));
// Creada la persona pedro
console.log(persona);

/*
{
    "juan": [...],
    "ana": [...],
    "pedro": {
        "casa": {
            "calle": "",
            "numero": "",
            "piso": {
                "planta": "",
                "puerta": ""
            }
        },
        "telefono": ""
    }
}

*/
```

---

**Respuesta original**

**NOTA:** Esta respuesta sólo comprueba que un objeto cualquiera contenga un array en cualquier punto.

Puedes hacer una función recursiva que vaya recorriendo tu objeto de manera jerárquica:

```
function has_array(o){
  if(Array.isArray(o)){
    return true;
  } else if (typeof(o) == 'object'){
    for(i in o){
      if (has_array(o[i])){
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Esta función devolverá `true` sólo si encuentra que la propiedad por la que está pasando es un array. Si detecta que es un objeto (cuidado con esto porque un array también se detecta como objeto con `typeof`, pero podrías utilizar el `constructor` para validarlo) recorre cada propiedad para hacer la misma validación.

En tu ejemplo no detecta array:

```
var persona = {
     "juan": {
         casa: {
             calle: "calle",
             numero: "1",
             piso: {
                 planta: "1",
                 puerta: "1"
             },
         },
         telefono:"612345789",
     },
     "ana": {
        casa: {
            calle: "calle2",
            numero: "2",
            piso: {
                planta: "2",
                puerta: "2"
            },
        },
        telefono:"612345789",
    }

 }

console.log(has_array(persona));
// undefined
```

Si modificamos tu entrada haciendo que un elemento telefono se llame ahora telefonos y sea un array devuelve `true`:

```
var persona = {
     "juan": {
         casa: {
             calle: "calle",
             numero: "1",
             piso: {
                 planta: "1",
                 puerta: "1"
             },
         },
         telefono:"612345789",
     },
     "ana": {
        casa: {
            calle: "calle2",
            numero: "2",
            piso: {
                planta: "2",
                puerta: "2"
            },
        },
        telefonos:["612345789"],
    }

 }
console.log(has_array(persona));
// true
```